# Installing SQL Server Express from SQL Server Developer Installer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-express

If I install SQL Server 2012 Express using the SQL Server 2012 developer installer, do I still have access to all features available from the **Advanced Services** and/or **With Tools** versions of SQL Server Express?

Or maybe I should be asking, what version of SQL Express comes with the Developer Edition?

1. SQL Server Express
2. SQL Server Express With Tools
3. SQL Server Express Advanced Services